# Checking values with Cucumber and Watir

Tags: cucumber, watir

I've been trying to get started with Cucumber and Watir. I've done the installation and written/copied a simple 'feature'. However, I'm not getting anywhere with checking what's on a page.

This my feature:

Feature: Search Google
    In order to make sure people can find my documentation
    I want to check it is listed on the first page in Google

```
Scenario: Searching for JS.Class docs
  Given I have opened "http://www.google.com/"
  When I search for "JS.Class"
  Then I should see a link to "http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/" with text "JS.Class v3.0"
```

My env.rb file looks like this

```
require 'watir'
require 'rspec'
```

And this is my search_steps.rb

```
@ie

Given /^I have opened "([^\"]*)"$/ do |url|
    @ie = Watir::IE.new
    @ie.goto(url)
end

When /^I search for "([^\"]*)"$/ do |arg1|
    @ie.text_field(:name, "q").set(arg1)
    @ie.button(:name, "btnG").click
end

Then /^I should see a link to "([^\"]*)" with text "([^\"]*)"$/ do |arg1, text|
    puts arg1

    # @ie.text.should include(arg1)
    @ie.close
end
```

When I uncomment the line '@ie.text.should include(arg1)' I get this error thrown.

```
Then I should see a link to "http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/" with text "JS.Class v3.0" # features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:13
  true
  undefined method `split' for ["http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/"]:Array (NoMethodError)
  ./features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:17:in `/^I should see a link to "([^\"]*)" with text "([^\"]*)"$/'

  features\search.feature:8:in `Then I should see a link to "http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/" with text "JS.Class v3.0"'
```

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features\search.feature:5 # Scenario: Searching for JS.Class docs

Right now the Then function isn't doing its job. If I comment out the line then all it's really doing is writing out some text.

The gems I have include the following cucumber <1.1.9>, rspec <2.9.0>, watir<2.0.4> and watir-webdriver <0.5.3>

The version of ruby I have is: ruby 1.9.3p125.

I'm running this on Windows 7 Ultimate.

I'm wondering if I'm missing a gem or something. Reading the message implies that I'm calling a method it can't find but I've found quite a few pages on the web that use this method.

Any help, guidance or pointers in the right direction are gratefully welcomed.

Comment: Can you run Cucumber with the `--backtrace` switch and post up the full error message?  It should give a better idea of where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you (manually) look at the text of the Google search results, you will noticed that there is no text "http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/". So, as expected, the test will fail.

To fix this, you can correct the call to the step by removing the 'http://':

```
Then I should see a link to "jsclass.jcoglan.com/" with text "JS.Class v3.0"
```

That said, it would be more robust if you actually make check for the link using the following code. Checking that the text is somewhere on the page can lead to false positives (see the latest post on [WatirMelon](http://watirmelon.com/2012/04/01/five-page-object-anti-patterns/))

```
@ie.link(:url => arg1, :text => text).exists?.should be true
```

Comment: Hi Justin, Thanks for the reply. I had initially used ie.html rather than ie.text. Beginners mistakes. I've tried using the code you've suggested but it throws the following error. "Compared using equal?, which compares object identity, but expected and actual ar not the same object. use 'actual.should == expected' if you don't care about object identity in this example." Now this makes me think it's looking at the type of the 'actual' object. I changed the 'be' to '==' but I receive a different error.

Comment: Odd, the code worked for me. However, I did a full uninstall and re-installed just the gems you mentioned and now I do get the error. Perhaps it was due to me having multiple rspec versions installed? At any rate, I'll take a look.

Comment: What is the error you get when you use '=='? The test is passing for me once I make this change.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have the following gems related to rspec. rspec <2.9.0>, rspec-core <2.9.0>, rspec-expectations <2.9.0> rspec-mocks <2.9.0>. Maybe it is just the case of me not having the correct version. Hope so, I was impressed by your answer and the improvement to checking for a link.

Comment: This is the error I get when using '=='. Then I should see a link to "jsclass.jcoglan.com" with text "JS.Class v3.0"
# features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:14
      jsclass.jcoglan.com
      expected: true
           got: false (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:18:in `/^I should see a link to "([^\"]*)" with text "([^\"]*)"$/'
      features\search.feature:8:in `Then I should see a link to "jsclass.jcoglan.com" with text "JS.Class v3.0"'

Comment: The second solution was based on your original step. Because `:url=>arg1` does an exact URL match, if you have changed the step to `Then I should see a link to jsclass.jcoglan.com`, it will give the error you see. You should either change it back to `http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/` or change the link locator to `:url=>/#{arg1}/` (ie use a regex).

Comment: Hi Justin. I used the regex which worked OK. I tried changing it back to jsclass.jcoglan.com/ but still got the error even when I removed the second part (:text => arg2). I'll stick with the regex since that answers my query. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you should also be able to use `xxx.should exist`  pretty sure I've used that before (although however I may have had some custom rspec matchers in place)

Comment: Chuck's suggestion seems better. No custom matchers required.

Comment: I know it's a late reply but I can't get the syntax right for Chuck's suggestion. Justin's version works for me.