# WATIR and Cucumber appears not to call the onclick event of the OBJECT tag

Tags: cucumber, watir

My colleague and I are new to Watir and Cucumber. He had written a few little ruby scripts using Watir and I'm now trying to 'translate' them into Cucumber.

In one of his tests, which works, he does the following:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
b.object(:id, 'TabContainer').click
```

I've found that using object doesn't work for me using Cucumber so I've done the following:

```
@ie = Watir::IE.new
@ie.element(:id, 'TabContainer').click
```

The OBJECT in question is:

```
<object height="120" width="50" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="TabContainer"
   name="TabContainer" data="/en-gb/swf/helpbounce.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

However, the click event doesn't work for me. Now, I know it isn't there as an attribute but it is present in helpbounce.swf and the WATIR only version works fine. 
Any advice or hints are gratefully welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of Cucumber should not impact whether or not Watir does or does not work.

My guess is that your env.rb is using `require 'watir'` when it should be using `require 'watir-webdriver'`.

Reason for this guess is that based on one of your previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980125/checking-values-with-cucumber-and-watir), it looks like you have Watir and Watir-Webdriver installed. At that time your env.rb was using Watir (not Watir-Webdriver).

However, given the code samples you've given, your colleague's tests are using Watir-Webdriver (as seen by the use of `b = Watir::Browser.new :ie`) where as you are trying to use Watir in your Cucumber tests (as seen by the use of `@ie = Watir::IE.new`).

So I think the solution to your problem is to switch your Cucumber tests to use Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: Hello, I didn't think Cucumber would affect Watir's working. I've not yet had opportunity to try your suggestion, although I strongly suspect it will work. When I do. I'll click the acceptance. Thanks.

Comment: it's nothing to do with cucumber, it's everything to do with which flavor of watir you are requiring.  Move to Watir-webdriver, it's the future.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer (since I think Justin has nailed the issue here) but more of a really strong recommendation.

1) If you have not already done so, immediately buy and read 'The Cucumber Book' from pragmatic programmers.  It will keep you on the right path with Cucumber (although myself I'd not use Capybara, which the authors like, but that's an individual choice)

2) as soon as possible, learn about Page Objects, it will make your code cleaner and far easier to maintain.   We had a great 4 hour session at the Test Automation Bazaar on page objects, cucumber, and watir.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/watir/watir-bazaar/wiki/Test-Automation-Workshop-2012) it would be worth every minute of your time that it takes to watch it and 'follow along' with all the exercises etc.

Comment: Hi Chuck (and Justin), thank you for the recommendation. The book is already on order though http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book and hopefully the Royal Mail have it in a sorting office for me to pick up tomorrow. Thanks also for the mention about page objects too. I'll be sure to follow that link up.

Comment: If you are in the UK and anywhere near London, hook up with some of the stuff sponsored by the SkillsMatter people, they are awesome.